# xmpp ejabberd - unable to create pub sub of type 'collection'

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I have tried setting the value of pubsub#node_type to 'collection' but the node type gets saved as 'flat' in the database.

I have also tried setting the value of pubsub#collection to an existing node, but the node_type value of the existing node still shows as flat.

I have also tried setting the node names to

```
'/group.abc' 
'/group.abc/group.xyz'
```

but it does not help. What other configurations need to set to create a pub sub node of type 'collection' ?

Thanks,

Comment: How did you configure pubsub module ? Did you enable DAG / collection support there ?

Comment: Yes i did enable it in the config file. I read in the documentation that DAG does not work with odbc. So i have dropped this idea for the time being.